# What do shaders encompass?

Tags: shaders

I'm researching shaders as I'm thinking about doing them for my final year project at Uni. I've looked at a lot of examples online and I think I get it. It's something that you apply to an object or scene in order to create a desired effect without changing the original object/scene, I think. I know that there are different types of shaders but that's the basic goal right?

Furthermore, what do shaders encompass? Are weather systems in games shaders? Particle effects? Landslides? I don't know where the line is drawn between animations/cinematics and shaders. Also I guess shaders which effect something in the game world, for example, a tower blowing up in BF4. The explosion itself would be shaders but the way the tower effects the world around it would be physics and collisions. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Shaders are a system for specifying *how* you want something to be managed by the GPU. There a different types of shaders, such as vertex shaders, fragment shaders, geometry shaders, etc.

### Vertex Shaders:

Models are built up of points, aka vertices. In order to move that object around in a scene, that model needs a matrix to direct how each vertex of the model should be transformed in order to display it in a desired position. Further, if the camera is to move, then that camera needs a matrix as well. These matrices get multiplied together, along with the vertex for the model all on the GPU in a vertex shader, directing **where the triangles should appear on the screen**.

### **Pixel/fragment Shaders:**

Once a triangle is defined, it needs to get filled in, otherwise it would just be wireframe. Fragment shaders direct how these triangles get filled in. These can take in values such as light sources as well as textures, and **output a color for a given pixel.**

### Geometry Shaders:

Particle effects can also use shaders. These can be managed by geometry shaders - a type of shader which can **output vertices** to a vertex shader, effectively generating particles without the overhead incurred by the CPU doing it.

### A Shader program:

A shader program is when all the basic types of shaders needed are **bound together**, such as a vertex & a fragment shader. Depending on how an application is built, there can be be many many many shader programs. An application can even define a separate shader to be used for post processing effects.

---

> Are weather systems in games shaders?

No, rather custom shaders could be used to define *how* a weather system should render.

> I don't know where the line is drawn between animations/cinematics and
>   shaders.

If it needs to display on the screen in some fashion, it will **employ** a shader program to direct how it should render.

Let me give you an example, if a box is to be rendered, the box would upload its vertices, UV's, and textures to the shader program. Next, it would use the vertex shader to direct how its triangles should appear on the screen. Then the GPU would use the fragment shader to direct how each texel should be filled in.